# Get event of UIPopoverPresentationController when dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I have viewControllerA from where I present the `UIPopoverPresentationcontroller` which display the static data.
Please find the below code for more information.

```
- (void)openPopupScreen:(id)sender {

    PopupViewController *popupVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popupViewController"];
    popupVC.delegate = self;
    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(220.0f, 230.0f);
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    _popupView = popupVC.popoverPresentationController;
    self.popupView.delegate = self;
    self.popupView.sourceView = self.view;
    self.popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 220.0f, 230.0f);           
    self.popupView.sourceRect = rect;
    [self presentViewController:popupVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As I did not write the code for dismiss the "popup" view as it is automatically dismissed when I simply touched on the view.

So my question is that I need the event when the popup is dismissed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you had already applied the delegate of `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` with below statement.

```
self.popupView.delegate = self;
```

**List of UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate methods.**

1) Called on the delegate when the popover controller will dismiss the popover. Return NO to prevent the
// dismissal of the view.

```
- (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController;
```

2) Called on the delegate when the user has taken action to dismiss the popover. This is not called when the popover is dimissed programatically.

```
- (void)popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController;
```

3) Notifies the delegate that the popover is about to be presented.

```
- (void)prepareForPopoverPresentation:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController;
```

For more information please check the [Apple Developer link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html).

For your reference `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` will call when you dismiss the popup.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` specifically at `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` method.

Answer (score 0):

try UIPopoverControllerDelegate method

```
    - (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
   //do stuff here...
}
```